# WCF SOA Service Client Registry

Tags: wcf, soa

I'm interested in creating a registry of sorts which would catalog all of the clients calling into a collection of WCF REST services.

I'd like to know:

- Who is calling (url)
- What service method are they calling

Does anyone have any recommendations of how this could be accomplished? Or perhaps references to implementations that currently exist?

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm in the same boat.  I've heard of software like SOASoft, AppFabric, UDDI, but haven't tried any of them or know if they will work for what we want.

Comment: We ended up giving each application its own id and then in each RESTful request we append the application id to the querystring. When the request arrives at the service it logs the application id along with the requested service and parameters. A crude yet effective implementation.